# Span click function, not clickable until an action is completed

Tags: jquery, html

I have a span tag acting as a button inside a form:-

```
<span id="next-step" name="next-step" class="next-step col-md-12">Next Step</span>
```

With a click function:-

```
  $('#next-step').click(function(){
    $('#step-1').fadeOut(100);
    $('#step-2').fadeIn(200);
  });
```

However, I don't want this to be clickable to start with. There are basically two steps in the process and I only want this to be clickable once information has been added.

I have tried adding a class as follows:-

```
$('#next-step').addClass('step-1');
```

Then setting the click function to `$('.step-1')` but this didn't work. Is there a better way of doing this?

I would use a `button` but then submits the form early which I don't want to happen.

Comment: FYI, you can make the button not submit the form by preventing its default behavior:
`$('button').click(function(evt){evt.preventDefault();});`

Comment: <button type="button" id="next-step" name="next-step" class="next-step col-md-12">Next Step</button> will not submit your form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So at this context, you have to use `event delegation` like below,

```
$(document).on("click", ".step-1", function(){
 //your code goes here
});
// where document should be any closest static parent of .step-1
```

The reason why we are using event delegation is that the element with class `.step-1` would not be available at the time of event binding. So we have to rely on event-bubbling's service under the hood of event delegation.